# Why wont my tableview display anything. It has the correct number of rows but no text. The data has been populated in a different viewcontroller(xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

```
import UIKit

class editViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{



@IBOutlet weak var loopTableView: UITableView!


//loop Data
var memberArr: [(String)] = []
var payArr: [(Int)] = []
var dateArr: [(String)] = []
var loopTypeArr: [(String)] = []
var holesArr: [(Int)] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    loopTableView.dataSource = self
    loopTableView.delegate = self
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

//Table view functions 
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return payArr.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "loopCell"){
        let loopCell = memberArr[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = loopCell
        return cell
        //"\(dateArr[indexPath.row])\t\(memberArr[indexPath.row])"
    }
    return UITableViewCell()
}   
}
```

Comment: where is your reloadTableView()? and why your assigning payArr.count in rowForIndex and memberArr in cellForRowAt? 
I would recommend you to read on basic UITableView implementation.

Comment: The payArr and memberArr always will have the same count. The code skips over the if let statement and returns UITableViewCell()

Comment: Based on the code which you've provided here I think you have forgot to [register the cells](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614888-register). Since the cell is not registered for the "loopCell" identifier it can't be dequed.